# Playwright equivalent for browser.executeScript of protractor

Tags: protractor, monaco-editor, playwright, playwright-test

I have something like this in protractor.

browser.executeScript(
'window.monaco.editor.getModel(monaco.Uri.parse("")).setValue(`' + someJavaScriptCode + '`)',
);

Can you help me with playwright equivalent of above code to replace contents of monaco editor?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`page.evaluate()` method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-evaluate):

```js
await page.evaluate(() => window.monaco.editor.getModel(monaco.Uri.parse("")).setValue(' + someJavaScriptCode + '));
```